# Angular 7 Universal in localhost

Tags: javascript, angular, server-side, angular-universal, universal

I just started angular universal but I would like to launch it in localhost no in prod.

I would like it to be built with every modification, but with each modification I have to restart the build with the command `npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr` to see the new modifications.

Is there a way to make it automatic at each save as the command `ng serve` ?

but I know that the command `ng serve` run the application in browser not in server.

I have try to build the browser application after the server application after compile server with --watch to see the modification and re build application. But it's not working.

Do you have any idea how to do ??

sorry for my English

Comment: You could write a bash script so you don't have to type out the command. Past that, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find how to do !

I created two angular project in angular.json, one for browser one for server

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "browserApp": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:class": {
          "spec": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "spec": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "spec": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:guard": {
          "spec": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:module": {
          "spec": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
          "spec": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:service": {
          "spec": false
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.browser.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.browser.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/robots.txt",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [{
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
              }],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [{
                "type": "initial",
                "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                "maximumError": "5mb"
              }]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "browserApp:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "browserApp:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "browserApp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "serverApp": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/server",
            "main": "src/main.server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [{
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
              }],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "none"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "browserApp-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "browserApp:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "browserApp:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "browserApp"
}
```

I launch 4 terminal

- ng build browserApp --watch
- ng build serverApp --watch
- webpack --mode development --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors --watch
- nodemon dist/server

and in google chrome I disable cache in Network tab.

do you think that is the right way ?